# Why does Team Fortress 2 have sub-tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, sub-tags

Ok, the title might seem a little stupid because I have no idea what this kind of thing is called. For example, when I click on [team-fortress-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-fortress-2), I see in the related tags section:

[tf2-spy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tf2-spy), [tf2-mann-vs-machine](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tf2-mann-vs-machine), [tf2-pyro](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tf2-pyro), [tf2-engineer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tf2-engineer), [tf2-heavy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tf2-heavy), the list goes on and on and on.

Aren't these technically all related to Team Fortress 2? Unlike Minecraft, which has different versions of gameplay (e.g. Minecraft-smp, minecraft-Bukkit), these tags are all about TF2. I guess you could says at picking a different character is kind of like another version of gameplay, but to me, its really all the same.

So what's the scope on this?

Comment: Also see [these two](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/4538/122) [related discussions](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4701/why-do-we-have-tags-like-diablo-3-demon-hunter) that came as a response to the diablo-3-class tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These kind of tags (I call them "subtags") were proposed/endorsed [by Jeff](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3302/a-personal-appeal-to-jeff-atwood-recent-changes-to-gaming/3304#comment8709_3304) as a solution to situations where having just the game tag isn't enough to meaningfully subdivide questions.  The intent is to use them for games that are likely to/starting to approach hundreds or even thousands of questions.

I went into some detail about my opinions on the subject [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4777/tags-are-bad-for-organization-and-require-more-effort-than-they-should), if you were wanting more of an opinion and less of a statement of facts. :)