# Rename [tf2-*] → [team-fortress-2-*]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-rename-request

We have a number of *Team Fortress 2* tags*, which were created during the era of 25 character tag names. Now that we have a 35 character limit for tag names, I recommend we rename the following tags:

- [tf2-demoman](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tf2-demoman) → [team-fortress-2-demoman](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-fortress-2-demoman)
- [tf2-engineer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tf2-engineer) → [team-fortress-2-engineer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-fortress-2-engineer)
- [tf2-heavy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tf2-heavy) → [team-fortress-2-heavy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-fortress-2-heavy)
- [tf2-mann-vs-machine](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tf2-mann-vs-machine) → [team-fortress-2-mann-vs-machine](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-fortress-2-mann-vs-machine)
- [tf2-medic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tf2-medic) → [team-fortress-2-medic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-fortress-2-medic)
- [tf2-pyro](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tf2-pyro) → [team-fortress-2-pyro](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-fortress-2-pyro)
- [tf2-scout](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tf2-scout) → [team-fortress-2-scout](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-fortress-2-scout)
- [tf2-sniper](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tf2-sniper) → [team-fortress-2-sniper](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-fortress-2-sniper)
- [tf2-soldier](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tf2-soldier) → [team-fortress-2-soldier](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-fortress-2-soldier)
- [tf2-spy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tf2-spy) → [team-fortress-2-spy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-fortress-2-spy)

The longest tag is [team-fortress-2-mann-vs-machine](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-fortress-2-mann-vs-machine), which is 31 characters.

<sub>* As established by [Why does Team Fortress 2 have sub-tags?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5706/47878) and reaffirmed with [Are game subtags still needed?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13000/47878)</sub>

Comment: Could downvoters please explain their reasoning? Is it because you don't think these tags should be renamed? Or because you don't like the idea of *Team Fortress 2* subtags in general?

Comment: From where I'm sitting sub-tags should always be used with the main game tag which gives the full, official game name already, so while I definitely think the subtags are useful, I don't necessarily think they need to be lengthened. It may go a long way if you could explain why renaming sub-tags would be beneficial in this instance? :)

Comment: For this game specifically I'd be hesitant because as a long time TF2 player, I can count the number of times I've said "Team Fortress 2" instead of TF2 on one hand. This is in contrast to, say, Fallout or Starcraft 2, and instead is similar to DotA / DotA 2 -- because really, when did someone last tell you they were playing "Defense of the Ancients Two"?

Comment: @Schism I generally go off of the Wikipedia name. "[Defense of the Ancients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_of_the_Ancients)" is the official name for the first installment, but "[Dota 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dota_2)" is the official name of the second installment. The Wikipedia name for this game is "[Team Fortress 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Fortress_2)", which is why I think it's best to make that the primary tag and keep "TF2" as a synonym.

Comment: @Schism I don't think how we pronounce something matters in this case. We already have a case with [the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim] tag, while no one actually pronounces it that way.

Comment: Upon reflection a half year later, Thunderforge's last comment convinces me.